# ImageView image issue

Tags: iphone, object, uiimageview, uiimage

What does the following error mean? 
And how can i avoid this?

> ImageIO:  JPEGNot a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xd9

Please advice, 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load not a JPEG file or corrupted FPEG file.

Comment: Thank you for your response Valeriy.

Comment: @OneDerr Siva, don't mention it. Just mark answer as accepted if it answers your question and fits your needs.

Comment: I hope the following link will help people facing the same problem. 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5081297/510480