# <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageReadGetBytesAtOffset in UIImagePNGRepresentation

Tags: ios, uiimage, uiimagepngrepresentation

The only other information I could find on this error was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019631/ios-8-1-crash-exc-bad-access-error-imageio-cgimagereadgetbytesatoffset), which wasn't helpful.

I get the following error when I try to save images. This seems to only happen when I have several images (~6) at once. It also seems to be completely random as to when it occurs. Sometimes everything is fine, sometimes it'll fail on 1 image, sometimes 3, and sometimes the app will completely crash in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

**Error: ImageIO: CGImageReadGetBytesAtOffset : ^^^ ERROR ^^^ CGImageSource was created with data size: 1144891 - current size is only: 1003855**

Here is the code that saves the image:

```
- (void)saveWithImage:(UIImage *)anImage andFileName:(NSString *)aFileName {
    NSString *subDirectory = @"Images";
    NSString *fileName = [aFileName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];

    NSString *documentsPath = [[CMAStorageManager sharedManager] documentsSubDirectory:subDirectory].path;
    NSString *imagePath = [subDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    __block NSString *path = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    __block NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(anImage);

    self.image = anImage;
    self.tableCellImage = anImage;
    self.galleryCellImage = anImage;
    self.imagePath = imagePath; // stored path has to be relative, not absolute (iOS8 changes UUID every run)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        if (![data writeToFile:path atomically:YES])
            NSLog(@"Error saving image to path: %@", path);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        });
    });
}
```

I get that error and as a result my images aren't saved (or only half of them are saved), which completely messes up the UI display, and any subsequent app launches. I've narrowed it down to the `UIImagePNGRepresentation` call.

On a related note, that code locks up the UI; I think because of the `UIImagePNGRepresentation` call; however, as far as I know `UIImagePNGRepresentation` is no thread safe, so I can't do it in the background. Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across a similar issue, this is what fixed it for me.

[iPhone iOS saving data obtained from UIImageJPEGRepresentation() fails second time: ImageIO: CGImageRead_mapData 'open' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685276/iphone-ios-saving-data-obtained-from-uiimagejpegrepresentation-fails-second-ti)

and this is the solution I used to save UIImages in a background thread:

[Convert UIImage to NSData without using UIImagePngrepresentation or UIImageJpegRepresentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239719/convert-uiimage-to-nsdata-without-using-uiimagepngrepresentation-or-uiimagejpegr)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because the api I called was throwing a 500 and returning html error page in the tmp >> NSData file I was trying to convert to PNG.

You may wish to check the file your trying to open is a image at all before conversion.

If youre downloading the file with dowloadTask then check statusCode is 200 before moving tmp > /Document/.png

[heres my answer in other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019631/ios-8-1-crash-exc-bad-access-error-imageio-cgimagereadgetbytesatoffset)